# Most efficient way to bin an array of geographic points?

Tags: c#, algorithm, geolocation, coordinates, binning

Term(s):

- Binning: in maps-based UI, the objective of binning is to help make spatial data more visible to the user. Rather than render each geographical point individually, it is easier to digest a 'bin' (e.g. a hexagonal or rectangular shape, like in the below example) with simpler information instead (e.g. the number of points the bin contains).

I am trying to bin a set of geographic points (example: http://a.tiles.mapbox.com/v3/devseed.map-hw6ew799/page.html#9/-0.3246/35.8887). I'm unsure if my approach is the most efficient implementation. Thoughts on my 'algorithm' or pointers would be appreciated.

I will be implementing this in C#.

Say I have a csv where each line is a (`lat`,`lon`) `point`. I read `n` of them and must render these `points` in bins to make the data easier to view on a map.

For this implementation I will try to bin the `points` into rectangular shapes (so what was in the example, except more square-y because it's simpler for calculations). Here it is:

1. Determine the maximum and minimum latitude and longitude for a total of 4 different values. These values will form my overall `bounding box` of all possible `points`. **Cost:** n=> **O(n)**`using a`for loop`, where`n`is the number of`points` I read.
2. Once I have the above 4 values, I will subdivide this big `bounding box` into a `HashMap`, mapping from single points to the respective mini-bounding `box object` (which will contain information like: what specific points it contains, its `point` `count`, its `bounds`, etc). **Cost:** a * b => **O(a * b)**, where `a` is the time it takes to construct a single `bounding box` and `b` is the number of `bounding boxes` constructed.
3. Then, re-iterate through the list of `points`, hashing each point to its respective bounding box. **Cost:** n => **O(n)**, where `n` is the number of points.

**Sum cost** (if I did this right): **O(n + b)**.

Is this the most efficient algorithm?

Thanks!

Comment: If the size of the boxes is constant, you probably can eliminate the first pass-- just build the boxes coming out of the first point. 

It's unclear what you're using this for exactly. Without this information, it's hard to answer your question.

Comment: You might want to check out data structures that are better suited to hold spatial information such as quadtrees or R-trees.